# gdal_retile.py modification needed

Tags: python, split, overlap, gdal

I need to split a set of large images into given x and y size tiles in overlapping fashion. I finally found GDAL in python and gdal_retile.py utility is capable to do most of what I need. Since my programming knowledge is weak, wanted to ask here;

1. I need gdal_retile.py take all large images in a given folder, create subfolders named as each of large image's name and create tiles within each corresponding folder.
2. This one may be a bit challenging. I have tested gdal_retile.py utility and its splitting big image perfectly, overlap etc. works well.
   But, when it reaches to end of image (right or bottom side), it creates a final tile piece, with remaining pixels. To be clear, for a 1000x1000 image with 300x300 tiles, it is creating 300x300, 300x300, 300x300 and 100x300 tiles for the first row. Same applies to last tile row.
   What I need is, instead of making a smaller final tile, I want it 300x300 too. So basically I need all tiles at same provided dimension (so the last tiles' overlap to previous one will be larger , but no problem with that).

I greatly apreciate if anyone can help me about these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the overlap option. As in your case you want 4 300x300 tiles in a row, you are left with 200 pixels too much, which has to be divided in 3 overlaps, resulting in overlaps of 200 / 3 = 67 pixels ( perhaps 66 works better)

The resulting command would be:

```
gdal_retile.py -overlap 67 -targetDir <yourTileDirectory> <your1000x1000inputfile>
```

Comment: (edited) Thanks for the comment. Actually the splits and overlaps I am going to apply will be chosen with some other criteria, therefore I cannot try to split them depending on current image size.